# Creating an auto-updating list in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, activerecord, associations

I have three relevant models:

```
class InventoryItem < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to  :item, :foreign_key => :item_id
    belongs_to  :vendor
    has_many    :shopping_list_items

class ShoppingList < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many    :shopping_list_items
    belongs_to  :user
end

class ShoppingListItem < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to    :shopping_list
  belongs_to    :inventory_item
end
```

What I am trying to do is create a sidebar shopping list that will autoupdate ShoppingListItem attributes (specifically price) when a respective attribute is changed in the InventoryItem table (again, price). My thinking was to have these three classes and map ShoppingListItems directly to InventoryItems, but I'm unsure of how to proceed with that. Alternatively, is it possible to do away with the ShoppingListItem class entirely and make ShoppingList be a collection of InventoryItems specified by the user? Any input is much appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why does ShoppingListItem have a price attribute? Shouldn't it simply refer to the price attribute of its associated InventoryItem?

Comment: Also, if ShoppingListItem does not have any attributes of its own, then yes, it is possible to do away with that model entirely. You'd be looking for a `has_and_belongs_to_many` relationship. This still requires a join table, but its entries are managed for you automatically by ActiveRecord -- you can do things like `shopping_list.inventory_items = InventoryItem.where(...)` and it will Just Work (usually).

Comment: My question was probably worded poorly, but yeah that was my goal. They will have identical attributes, so I do like the idea of getting rid of the extra model at this point. So the InventoryItem model should contain: `has_and_belongs_to_many :shopping_lists` yeah?

Comment: Having worked on a project in which users bought vouchers, the one reason you might want the ShoppingListItem to have its own price would be to maintain the history of the price at exact time the item was added to cart, rather than a new price. But you seem to be saying that you do want the price updated, so I would agree with @Grantovich that you should just do away with the ShoppingListItem join model.

Comment: Interesting point Carlos, thanks. For this purpose I won't likely need any price history, but good to think about for future projects (:

Comment: @settheline Yes, and ShoppingList will contain `has_and_belongs_to_many :inventory_items`. Not sure why you say that ShoppingListItem would have had identical attributes to InventoryItem -- I assume from your response that you do only want to store the information once, instead of duplicating it (as Carlos suggested a use case for).

Comment: I reformulated my comments as an answer -- if this is indeed what you were looking for, I'd appreciate if you could accept it. =)

Comment: Yes indeed it was, thank you. Just got back to SO and saw your answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To redo my comments as a real answer, yes, it is possible to forego the `ShoppingListItem` model in this case, as long as you don't need to attach any data to that model itself (e.g. the time the item was added to the list). You could link your models as follows with a `has_and_belongs_to_many` association:

```
class InventoryItem < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :item
    belongs_to :vendor
    has_and_belongs_to_many :shopping_lists
end

class ShoppingList < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :user
    has_and_belongs_to_many :inventory_items
end
```

This will allow you to assign an array of inventory items to the `inventory_items` attribute of a shopping list, and Rails will create or delete the necessary join records automatically. [More information from the Rails guides.](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#has-and-belongs-to-many-association-reference) Note that you'll still need a join table in your schema -- there just isn't a model associated with it. In your case, the migration might look like this:

```
create_table :inventory_items_shopping_lists, id: false do |t|
  t.references :inventory_item
  t.references :shopping_list
end

add_index :inventory_items_shopping_lists, :inventory_item_id
add_index :inventory_items_shopping_lists, :shopping_list_id
add_index :inventory_items_shopping_lists, [:inventory_item_id, :shopping_list_id], unique: true
```

Note that in order for Rails to auto-detect the table, its name should be the combined plural forms of both models in alphabetical order. Otherwise you need to specify the table name using the `join_table` option when defining the association.